# get properties - VectorLayer

Tags: openlayers

How to get some properties at VectorLayer (ol/layer/Vector)
I just want to simplicity code and wonder it is possible get e.g.
**title** and use this properties to get value from localStorage
Tray: this.title, getProperties(title), get.title, title and have undefined or void in browser.

Code:

```
export const v_alarm_co = new VectorLayer({
source: cluSource,
style: sFeature,
title: "alarm co",
// this work --> visible: localStorage.getItem("alarm co") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("alarm co")) : true,
   visible: localStorage.getItem(getProperties(title)) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(getProperties(title))) : true,
opacity: 1,
description: "Alarm c.o."
});
```

And code to set value on LocalStorage which work proper:

```
const setLocalStorage = new Button({
html: "S",
className: "custom-user",
title: "Save user layer settings.",
handleClick: () => {
map.getLayers().forEach((layers) => {
 localStorage.setItem(layers.get("title"), JSON.stringify(layers.getVisible()));
  if (layers instanceof GroupLayer) {
    layers.getLayers().forEach((layer) => {
      localStorage.setItem(layer.get("title"), JSON.stringify(layer.getVisible()));
    });
  }
});
localStorage.setItem("center", JSON.stringify(map.getView().getCenter()));
localStorage.setItem("zoom", JSON.stringify(map.getView().getZoom()));
}
});
```

OpenLayers v. 6.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I do it in that way:

```
var featurething = new Feature({  geometry: new Point([x,y]     ),verlinkung: '<a   
href="http://www.hsv.de">hallo</a>',     });
featurethingSource.addFeature( featurething );

const zusatzLayer = new VectorLayer({
source: featurethingSource,
style: new Style({
image: new CircleStyle({
radius: 10,
fill: new Fill({color: 'rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.7)'}),
stroke: new Stroke({color: 'red', width: 3}),
})
})
});
  
map.addLayer(zusatzLayer);
```

...
....

```
map.on("click", (event) => {
var features = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(event.pixel);
if (features && features.length > 0) {
var ausgabe = features[0].get("verlinkung");
alert (ausgabe)
}
});
```